# I'm trying to embed an interactive image within Webflow but the line breaks in my content are not showing up

Tags: javascript, webflow

So I am working on an interactive image for a client website and I used this site to make the image interactive: https://imagemarker.com/discover.html

The image looks great, however the code that they give you is an absolute mess, and I'm having some issues embedding it..

I was able to pick out the html code and add it to the page code, and then I put the rest of the script code within the embed element. This works, but the only issue is that the line breaks in my interactive content are not showing up, its all coming it as one line, and I don't understand the problem since I'm very amateur when it comes to coding...

This is the code that I received through the website: https://gist.github.com/timeanator/5ad0f3da36496cbd4fc3dd364ab680e9

Here is what the interaction is supposed to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YgWo.jpg
This is what it currently looks like on webflow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO8dT.jpg

I feel like it's an easy fix, but I am so dumb when it comes to coding, any help is hugely appreciated!!

Read only webflow link: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/timeas-awesome-project?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=timeas-awesome-project&preview=4021eaac3f6f76bb92ac1840cbfa741b&mode=preview

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have shared on gist has the same problem as you have described happening on your webflow website. I think the problem is with the text output from imagemarker. Replacing the `\n` with `<br />` in the text section will fix the problem.

[Codesandbox link (I have modified line 105 as a sample)](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-fermi-p071t?file=/index.html)
Codesandbox also formatted the code to show exactly where text is.

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out while looking through the code and was just about to delete my question lol

Thank you though! Do you know why imagemaker uses \n instead of <br>? is it an old way of coding line breaks?

Comment: `\n` is the line break character in text file but is not supposed to work in HTML at all. HTML ignores regular line-break character. I think this might be a bug in imagemarker code because it breaks WYSIWYG for their users.

Comment: You should leave the question so that it might help other people who see similar issues with using imagemarker.